# Is it possible to keep the input Markup with DaisyDiff?

Tags: java, html, diff

So, I currently struggle to implement a diffing tool, which is capable of diffing two HTML Files. I did some research and ended up using DaisyDiff. Since this tool seems to be a bit aged now, I struggle to find some examples, that still work. I found [this quesion on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508000/how-do-i-call-daisydiff-to-compare-two-html-files), since I could not figure out, what to pass as 3rd and 4th argument, and it helped. The current state of my implementation:

```
String html1 = "<html class='foobar'>Hello</html>";
String html2 = "<html>Bye</html>";

try {
    StringWriter finalResult = new StringWriter();
    SAXTransformerFactory tf = (SAXTransformerFactory) SAXTransformerFactory.newInstance(); 
    TransformerHandler result = tf.newTransformerHandler(); 
    result.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes"); 
    result.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes"); 
    result.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html"); 
    result.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8"); 
    result.setResult(new StreamResult(finalResult)); 

    ContentHandler postProcess = result; 

    DaisyDiff.diffHTML(new InputSource(new StringReader(html1)), new InputSource(new StringReader(html2)), postProcess, null, Locale.GERMAN);

    System.out.println(finalResult.toString());

} catch (SAXException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem is, that it acutally only diffs the plain Text but it completly removes the Markup from the input. For example, if I put these two strings as input:

```
String first = "<div>Hello</div>"
String second = "<div>Bye</div>"
```

I would expect this output:

```
<div><span class="removed">Hello</span><span class="added">Bye</span></div>
```

But I only get this instead:

```
<span class="removed">Hello</span><span class="added">Bye</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I finally got it to work. After I found [this example code](https://github.com/Banno/daisydiff-sbt/blob/master/src/test/java/org/outerj/daisy/diff/html/HtmlTestFixture.java) on Github, it was clear, that the issue was not the `ContentHandler`, as I suspected. So, if anyone also needs to diff some HTML, and does not want to waste a few days searching for a good (and working) example, this is how I got it working.

First, you need to download the [NekoHTML Dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.nekohtml/nekohtml), which is basically a HTML Parser.

Thats how my import block looks like

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXTransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.TransformerHandler;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.outerj.daisy.diff.helper.NekoHtmlParser;
import org.outerj.daisy.diff.html.HTMLDiffer;
import org.outerj.daisy.diff.html.HtmlSaxDiffOutput;
import org.outerj.daisy.diff.html.TextNodeComparator;
import org.outerj.daisy.diff.html.dom.DomTreeBuilder;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
```

And here is my full implementation of the Differ, which does not remove the actual Markup (please note that this is not really my code, I just got the example I linked above working!):

```
public static String diffHtml(String first, String second) throws TransformerConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {

    StringWriter finalResult = new StringWriter();
    SAXTransformerFactory tf = (SAXTransformerFactory) SAXTransformerFactory.newInstance();

    TransformerHandler result = tf.newTransformerHandler();
    result.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    result.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    result.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
    result.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    result.setResult(new StreamResult(finalResult));

    ContentHandler postProcess = result;

    Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
    String prefix = "diff";

    NekoHtmlParser cleaner = new NekoHtmlParser();

    InputSource oldSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(first));
    InputSource newSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(second));

    DomTreeBuilder oldHandler = new DomTreeBuilder();
    cleaner.parse(oldSource, oldHandler);
    TextNodeComparator leftComparator = new TextNodeComparator(oldHandler, locale);

    DomTreeBuilder newHandler = new DomTreeBuilder();
    cleaner.parse(newSource, newHandler);
    TextNodeComparator rightComparator = new TextNodeComparator(newHandler, locale);

    HtmlSaxDiffOutput output = new HtmlSaxDiffOutput(postProcess, prefix);

    HTMLDiffer differ = new HTMLDiffer(output);
    differ.diff(leftComparator, rightComparator);

    System.out.println(finalResult.toString());

    return finalResult.toString();
}
```

Oh, and if you are getting an Error with the `IProgressMonitor` Interface, please note, that it was moved from `org.eclipse.core.runtime` to `org.eclipse.equinox.common`, so keep in mind to use the correct dependency. Also stumbled upon this little problem. I hope this helps!